# Name That ...Name? 9

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

A short King on a climber with a 2016 leave

An exam man wrestled with a dangerous sport to weave

Name the name

Hint 1

> "Exam man" is a reference to the sports' players last name

Hint 2

> A climber is a vertical *Vine*

Comment: What are those two capitalized S and K doing there

Comment: Grace period? What is that? Do you know? $(+1)$ by the way (and the bounty only ended an hour ago!) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the name

> Zachary?

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

> [Zachary Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachary_Taylor) - the 12th President of the United States, he is surely more important than Taylor Swift.

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

> [Pope Zachary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Zachary) (not sure about this one) He is a diplomat so 'no divine rift'.

A short King on a climber with a 2016 leave

> Short for Zachary is Zach, [Zach King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zach_King) is a viner (from the clue: climber + the second  hint) who retired from the platform in 2016. And Vine was also kind of dead in the late 2016.

An exam man wrestled with a dangerous sport to weave

> [Zachary Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zack_Test) is a former American rugby player.

Comment: Amazing Job! You've solved it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the answer might be

> Tom

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

> Swift as in Taylor Swift --> Tom Tailor

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

> This is maybe referring to Tom Pope, an English football player, and "as long as there's no divine rift" means that the "pope" isn't referring to religion (the real Pope)

Comment: No, it isn't Tom

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Marie

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

> Marie Antoinette's dress designer, Rose Bertin, was relied upon "to defeat [Antoinette's] enemies with style".

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

> Pope Pius VI, who was Pope for 24 years during Antoinette's life, has a short and easy to remember name (Pious/Pius). In addition he condemned the French Revolution (a revolt against the monarchy and the divine right to rule) - a Divine rift.

Comment: Good guess, but no

Answer (score 0):

The name is

> Andrew

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

> [Andrew Taylor Still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Taylor_Still), founder of osteopathy, is arguably more important historically than singer Taylor Swift

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

> There is a singer named Andrew Pope. Not sure what makes him easy to keep in mind, though...

A short King on a climber with a 2016 leave

> James King -> Jamie -> [Jamie Andrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Andrew), who climbed the Matterhorn in 2016

An exam man wrestled with a dangerous sport to weave

> [Andrew Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28wrestler%29) fought in the WWF/WWE with the stage name "Test".

Comment: No, it is not Andrew

Answer (score 0):

> Alexander

My clothing designer had a lot more importance than Swift

> Alexander Taylor

My pope is easy to keep in mind, as long as there's no divine rift

> Alexander Pope

Not so sure on the other two, but it is possible.

Comment: No, this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a reference to

> Jonathan Swift here

is that the Swift?

Not sure where to go from there.

The climber line is confusing me and making me think of

> Martin Short on a ladder with Etta King or Martin Luther King -

none of which is relevant.

Is it

> Jonathan?

and is exam man

> Proctor?

Too bad I know nothing about sports!

Comment: No, it isn't Jonathan